# How to Add discount code form to multi shipping address

Tags: frontend, ce-1.9.0.1, coupon-codes

I have been working for 2 days for applying multiple coupon on cart I know there are modules which are available for that. But i don't want to use it. I want some custom code so that i can apply more than 1 coupon code in the single order.

Please help. i am very tired after working on the same stuff.